# How do I use external crates with the Rust compiler explorer?

Tags: rust

Is it possible to use crates from crates.io with [Matt Godbolt's Rust compiler explorer](https://rust.godbolt.org/)? If so, how?

Here's [my failed attempt](https://godbolt.org/z/DnDG8r).

Comment: AFAIK, no. I believe this to be for security reasons. The [official Rust playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/) has some (but not all) crates and allows inspecting the LLVM and assembly output of a program, but not with as many features.

Comment: At some point, you should consider doing your investigation locally.

Answer (score 1):

There is an (at time of writing still open) issue against Compiler Explorer asking for the ability to use commonly used Rust crates:

https://github.com/compiler-explorer/compiler-explorer/issues/2523

<sub>(Old: https://github.com/compiler-explorer/compiler-explorer/issues/754)</sub>